# Material-ui example

Tags: material-design, reactjs

I got this code snippet from [Material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu)(Simple example) website itself and it seems it doesn't work immediately by just copying and paste directly.

It throws an error **Unexpected token ("line#") while parsing**, particularly in the handleChange = ....... . I'm currently using Visual Studio Code and i'm also new to using Material-ui in JSX.

What am i missing? Please help.

```
import React from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/lib/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

export default class DropDownMenuSimpleExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 2};
  }

  handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

  render() {
    return (
      <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never"/>
        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night"/>
        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights"/>
        <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends"/>
        <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly"/>
      </DropDownMenu>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});` to

```
handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value})
};
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that the examples in this documentation use ES6 syntax and therefore if you are testing these examples in your own project you need to have the proper plugins installed in your compiler. To use the ES6 syntax as shown in the example `handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});` you need to install the plugin for Babel. You can find more info on Babel and how to use it [HERE](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/). If you haven't started using ES6 syntax, I highly recommend giving it a try. Hope that helps.